# MS EXCEL check content if right or left cell side

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi I need to check if the content of a cell is on right or left side from an output,

for example

```
[CHECK                ]
[CHECK                ]
[                CHECK]
[                CHECK]
[CHECK                ]
[                CHECK]
```

and I need another output sayng that if text is on left, do an multiply for example, otherwise leave it, so

```
[CHECK*2   ]
[CHECK*2   ]
[CHECK     ]
[CHECK     ]
[CHECK*2   ]
[CHECK     ]
```

results, is this doible?

Comment: I think you need to clarify why the content is on the left or right. Is it down to formatting, or does the cell contain padded text resembling a value? Have you made any attempt to come up with some code yourself to identify the difference?

Comment: Looking at [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) may give you a hint ;)

Comment: well thats the thing, I exported the results, and there is no styling in what so ever, I dont ujdnerstand how its even styling it, I mean I coulve used find and select if its aligned to right, but there is no aligment. What so far the content of the cells are numbers, and if its on left side its in some currency, if its on other its in other currency, I need to divide it.

Comment: so you have different currencies and want to set a factor to one of them?

Comment: okey, Ill give u an example, Ive red what ive wrote and saw its actually confusing, so hare. I have this type of cells

[23.00______]
[______20.11]
[23.00______]
[______20.11]

On the left side, there is Euros and on right isde there is Pounds,
I need to multiply pounds so it would become Euros. Since I need the output only of euros.

Comment: How about checking the length of the cell to see what's really there? Use `=LEN(A1)` in a cell or `Debug.Print LEN(Range("A1"))` in the VBE to examine it. If there is padding, then just check `=LEFT(A1,1)` or `Debug.Print LEFT(Range("A1"),1)` for a space or not.

Comment: Thanks, ran it trough, now I just need to make formula so it would multiply if its more, Ive made a second row that say 1 and 99999 if its 1 then eur, otherwise 9999, so I need to multiply the number if its bigger, so far Ive got htis, but it drops "#Value" error on multiply.

Comment: =PRODUCT(IF(A1>B1;A1*3.14;A1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this UDF:

```
Function CALCULATE_ALIGNMENT(cur As Double, rng As Range)

On Error Resume Next
CALCULATE_ALIGNMENT = rng.Value

If rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft Then
    CALCULATE_ALIGNMENT = cur * rng.Value
End If

End Function
```

Use it as:

```
=CALCULATE_ALIGNMENT(2,B2)
```

where:
B2 is your aligned range
2 is your multiplication value (you can also put reference like $C$1)